# Error: Missing parameter values. What's wrong with the code?

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

This is my load method:
The datasource here is a stored procedure, I am trying to get values from the query and send it as a parameter to the stored procedure, What I am doing wrong?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection myConnection =
            new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection( "user id=;" +
                    "password=;server=localhost;" +
                    "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                    "database=;" + "db;" + 
                    "connection timeout=30");

        myConnection.Open();

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand myCommand_FirstName =
            new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand( "SELECT [Patient-ID] " +
                 "FROM [Patient-Info] " +
                 "WHERE [First Name]='" + Request.QueryString["param3"] + 
                 "' AND [Last Name]='" + Request.QueryString["param4"] + "';"
                 , myConnection);

        String patient_ID = "";
        if (myCommand_FirstName.ExecuteScalar() != null)
        {
            patient_ID = myCommand_FirstName.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        }

        CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument reportDocument = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();
        CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        ParameterField paramField = new ParameterField();
        ParameterFields paramFields = new ParameterFields();
        paramField.Name = "@ID";
        ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        paramDiscreteValue.Value = patient_ID;
        paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
        paramFields.Add(paramField);

        paramField = new ParameterField();
        paramField.Name = "@Med";
        paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        paramDiscreteValue.Value = Request.QueryString["param1"];
        paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
        paramFields.Add(paramField);

        paramField = new ParameterField();
        paramField.Name = "@Year";
        paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        paramDiscreteValue.Value = Request.QueryString["param2"];
        paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
        paramFields.Add(paramField);

        reportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport1.rpt"));
        CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument;

        myConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

And this is where I have defined the CrystalReportViewer:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div>
        <CR:CrystalReportViewer  ID="CrystalReportViewer1" width="903px" height="1170px" runat="server" AutoDataBind="True"  ToolPanelView="None" OnInit="CrystalReportViewer1_Init" DisplayToolbar="False" EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt="False" GroupTreeImagesFolderUrl="" ReportSourceID="CrystalReportSource1" ToolbarImagesFolderUrl="" ToolPanelWidth="200px" EnableParameterPrompt="False"    />
        <CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource1" runat="server">
            <Report FileName="CrystalReport1.rpt">
            </Report>
        </CR:CrystalReportSource>
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

please set parameters like below:

```
    reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@ID", patient_ID);
    reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@Med", Request.QueryString["param1"]);
    reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@Year",  Request.QueryString["param2"]);
```

Comment: And please set property  AutoDataBind="true" in aspx page

Comment: I tried all you are saying, but unfortunately didn't work!